# Mysql query from more tables

Tags: mysql

i have this db tables structure:

users

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+
| id | name         | last_name       |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
| 1  |Matteo        |Del Mastro       |
| 2  |Giovanni      |Di Genova        |
| 3  |Francesco     |Moccia           |
| 4  |Vincenzo      |Rossi            |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
```

user_extra

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+
| id | user_id      | phone           |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
| 1  |1             |3632562352       |
| 2  |2             |3684647333       |
| 3  |3             |3638543262       |
| 4  |4             |3633364655       |
+----+--------------+-----------------+
```

company_users

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+----------+
| id | company_id   | dipartimento_id | user_id  |
+----+--------------+-----------------+----------+
| 1  |1             |1                | 1        |
| 2  |1             |2                | 2        |
| 3  |1             |3                | 3        |
| 4  |1             |3                | 4        |
+----+--------------+-----------------+----------+
```

dipartimenti

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | sub_id       | company_id      | name        |
+----+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1  |NULL          |1                |Comando      |
| 2  |1             |1                |Sez. Analisi |
| 3  |2             |1                |NIL Roma     |
| 4  |2             |1                | NIL Latina  |
+----+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now, I need to select all users (grouped by department) with the same company_id and same department

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS User.*,CompanyUser.*,UserExtra.*,CompanyDipartimenti.id,Comp‌​anyDipartimenti.name FROM users AS User LEFT JOIN company_users AS CompanyUser ON (User.id=CompanyUser.user_id) LEFT JOIN user_extras AS UserExtra ON (User.id=UserExtra.user_id) LEFT JOIN dipartimentis AS CompanyDipartimenti ON (CompanyUser.dipartimento_id=CompanyDipartimenti.id OR CompanyUser.dipartimento_id=CompanyDipartimenti.sub_id) WHERE 1 AND CompanyUser.company_id='1' GROUP BY CompanyUser.id, CompanyUser.dipartimento_id ORDER BY User.dt_last_login DESC LIMIT 0,50

Comment: Can you also share with us what you have tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you're asking for using "INNER JOIN" on the tables that you want to compare

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS User.*,CompanyUser.*,UserExtra.*,CompanyDipartimenti.id,CompanyDipartimenti.name FROM users AS User LEFT JOIN company_users AS CompanyUser ON (User.id=CompanyUser.user_id) LEFT JOIN user_extras AS UserExtra ON (User.id=UserExtra.user_id) LEFT JOIN dipartimentis AS CompanyDipartimenti ON (CompanyUser.dipartimento_id=CompanyDipartimenti.id OR CompanyUser.dipartimento_id=CompanyDipartimenti.sub_id) WHERE 1 AND CompanyUser.company_id='1' GROUP BY CompanyUser.id, CompanyUser.dipartimento_id ORDER BY User.dt_last_login DESC LIMIT 0,50

Comment: Please edit your question to include code. Instead of adding it as a comment